# Setting which events I want my directives to listen to

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have a directive like so:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('epw')
  .directive('md-title', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
      scope: {
        listenTo: '@'
      },
      controller: function () {
        $rootScope.$on('event', function (e, msg) {
          console.log('do something');
        }); // how to I dynamically change what to listen to using the scope `listenTo`
      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'md-title.html'
    }
  });
```

I have this:

```
<md-title listen-to="TITLE_SELECTION_UPDATED"></md-title>
```

and

```
<div class="m-section-header">
  <h1 class="epw-header">{{ctrl.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.listenTo` as the event to listen for...

```
controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on($scope.listenTo, function (e, msg) {
        console.log('do something');
    }); 
}
```

Note:  I am also injecting `$scope` and `$rootScope` into the directive's controller function.

Note #2:  I'm not sure why you are using `$rootScope.$on` instead of just `$scope.$on` for your event listener.  Are you sure you want to be using `$rootScope` for this?

Comment: ah yes, I need to use $rootScope as I wanted the directive to be decouple and to have the $rootScope to be the only thing injected in the directive, I would need to try this XD

Comment: instead of using $scope, I used `this`